# Reporting Services - Dynamic grand total with multiple lines using Matrix

Tags: c#, vba, reporting-services

I need to be able to use custom code to allow summing on the different Level 4 descriptions an show a grand total on the Level 4 descriptions.  This is a matrix report.

Here the report

[Report Image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HANOb.png)

[image]

```
Level 3      Level 4          2016-009    2016-010   2016-011
Arcadia      Personnel Rel     100          120        11
Arcadia      Other Expenses    100           10         1 
Arcadia      Shipping Rel      100           20         2

             Total             300          150        14

Chicago      Personnel Rel     1             30        10 
Chicago      Other Expenses    2             10        10
Chicago      Shipping Rel      100           10        10

             Total             103           50        30

Grand Total  Personnel Rel     101          150        21
             Other Expenses    102           20        11
             Shipping Rel      200           30        12

Final Total                    403          200        44
```

I started using custom code like this but I need to do some type of collection storing the description with the correct totals for each period.

Using this expression on the detail line

```
=Code.AddTotal(Sum(Fields!Activity_Amt.Value), Field!Period_Nbr.Value, Field!Level4.Value)
```

This code should kept track of the Level 4 description totals

Custom Code

```
 Public Shared detailTotal as New Collection

Public Function AddTotal(ByVal value as Double, ByVal period as String, ByVal level4 as String) as Object

Dim subtotal as Double
Dim combineStr = period & "" &level4

if  not detailTotal.Contains(combineStr) Then
   detailTotal.Add(value, combineStr)
   subtotal = detailTotal.item(combineStr)
   return subtotal
end if

subtotal = detailTotal.item(combineStr) + value
detailTotal.remove(combineStr)
detailTotal.add(subtotal,combineStr)
return detailTotal.item(combineStr)
end function
```

Comment: So do you have some code already?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: @RobertThompson, Level 3 and Level 4 are groups in your matrix? How are you calling the function and what is its expected behaviour? Add a screenshot of your matrix in the Design window.

Comment: I have added more information

Answer (score 0):

Even if you store the description in a collection you cannot use it to produce rows in a tablix. I think you have two options. First is create embed a tablix inside a cell in your matrix to calculate the total per description; the second option (which I recommend) is to add three rows outside the scope of any group and hardcode the description in each one.

[image]

Note the Grand Total rows and Final Total are outside the scope of Level 3 and Level 4 Row Groups, that is the trick. Also note each description is hardcoded in the cell, so you will have to add manually a row per description in your dataset.

Then for calculating the `Grand Total` in each row (Green) use a specific expression as follows. For `Personnel Rel` total use:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Level_4.Value="Personnel Rel",Fields!Activity_Amt.Value,0))
```

For `Other Expenses` use:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Level_4.Value="Other Expenses",Fields!Activity_Amt.Value,0))
```

And for `Shipping Rel` use:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Level_4.Value="Shipping Rel",Fields!Activity_Amt.Value,0))
```

In the `Final Total` row just use:

```
=SUM(Fields!Activity_Amt.Value)
```

It should produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro for the quick response.   I am a little confuse on what you are saying on the following.  ** "Add three rows outside the scope of any group and hardcode the description in each one."**.  Are you saying create 3 rows and hide them to do the calculation.

Comment: @RobertThompson, I mean you have to insert three adittional rows below Total row to calculate the total per Level 4 Description.

Comment: Ok.  I just found this link 5 mins ago. And this did the job. https://sqlserverreportingservices.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/adding-a-group-to-a-matrix-to-create-subtotals/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this link to help resolve my problem.

https://sqlserverreportingservices.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/adding-a-group-to-a-matrix-to-create-subtotals/

I did a Right click Add Group => Adjacent Below on the sub total

[Click this link to review the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG3EI.png)